# Where do GCE compute instance accounts come from when creating new instances?

Tags: security, google-compute-engine

I created a brand new instance in a Google Compute Engine project, and I see in the logs where the instance creates new accounts-from-metadata.  Some of the accounts created had been removed from the project permissions.

For example in project Permissions, I have:

```
nnnn@project.gserviceaccount.com
realuser1@gmail.com
realuser2@gmail.com
myownacct@domain.com
projectname@appspot.gservice.com
realuser3@gmail.com
```

The log entries from instance creation shows it's creating user accounts in the instance for users who had been removed from the project.  It also doesn't show realuser3 who was added to the project permissions.

```
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account (deleted1 user account)
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account (realuser1 user account)
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account (myownacct user account)
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account user
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account ubuntu
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account (deleted2 user account)
(instance-name) accounts-from-metadata: INFO Creating account (previous google support user)
```

I expect to see realuser3, and I don't expect deleted users with no project permission to have accounts created on a fresh image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accounts inside the VM are separate from the accounts that have permission to operate on the API.

The accounts in the VM come from the sshKeys metadata value that the VM sees.  This is a union of VM specific metadata and the project metadata.

By default `gcutil` will prompt you to create a key and expand the `sshKeys` metadata value with that key and `$USER`.  The easiest way to see and edit this is at the [Cloud Console](http://cloud.google.com/console).  There are more details on ssh'ing into the instance [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances#sshing).

Comment: I'm still confused.  The logs are from a new instance web serial console, I haven't been able to log into yet so there shouldn't be any sshKeys metadata.  The log shows it created accounts which had been removed from the project permissions months ago.  Therefore if the users don't exist in project permissions, and doesn't exist from ssh connection, the user accounts shouldn't exist.

Comment: The script won't remove any user accounts to avoid data loss.

Check for sshKeys via `gcutil getproject` and `gcutil getinstance <instance name>` also to make sure you aren't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that answered my question.

$ gcutil getproject - did show sshKeys for accounts which didn't exist in permissions page.

Permissions page:
        https://cloud.google.com/console/project/apps~(project)/teams

Metadata page:
        https://cloud.google.com/console/project/apps~(project)/compute/metadata

Navigating to the metadata page (located under Compute Engine, not the main project) and deleting all the sshKeys entries removed the reappearing accounts.